# Sequelize Bad Handshake error

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a new `azure MySQL` server and I am trying to use that with my existing `Nodejs` app.

When I try to connect to the `Mysql` instance from my terminal(using mysql command), I am able to successfully connect.

However, We I try to connect through my Nodejs app, which is using sequentialize for ORM, I am unable to connect.

It shows the following error

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: ER_HANDSHAKE_ERROR: Bad handshake
```

Please find my code below

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
  "host": config.host,
  "dialect": "mysql",
  "dialectOptions": {
    "ssl": {ca:fs.readFileSync("./MyCert.crt")},
    insecureAuth: true
  }
});
```

FYI: I am using sequelize@2.0.0

kindly help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed in the latest sequelize version(>4.0)